# How can I benchmark editor productivity objectively?

Tags: vim, editor, benchmarking

I'm not sure if Vim makes me more productive compared to other editors/ide's like Eclipse for example.

But somehow I get an empowering feeling when using Vim and noticed resistance to trying others editors.

Example: As soon a I see some cool feature in an other editor I'm thinking "*Vi can do that* (i just have to find the keystroke or configure a plugin)"

How can I benchmark editor productivity objectively?

My ideal editor would be: [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org) feature set and ease of use, but with SublimeText's performance and slick looks.

**Update**
[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is now my primary code editor.
[Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com/) for config files and quick edits.
[Vim](http://vim.org/) for ssh sessions or editing with macros.

Comment: The "title" field is for your question. It's not some random place for you to enter a theme or off-hand comment. Please put your actual question in that field in the future.

Comment: I found "Addicted to Vim" a more juicy title. But you're right so I added the "addicted theme" to the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say those symptoms are subjective clues that you're probably more productive in Vim - frustration with other tools is likely to be a fairly good indicator.

I would say with a huge degree of certainty that if you're into Vim deep enough to get frustrated with other editors, any productivity gain from switching is likely to be very small.

Answer (score 4):

If you like writing code in vim then that alone is a pretty good reason to use vim.

What good would a tool be that made you 2% more productive (according to some study) but that you didn't like as much? I tell you, working with tools you like is pretty darn important!

Answer (score 4):

I also I'm addicted to the Vi input model, I'm sure that it makes me more productive.

I feel uncomfortable when I use some other editors. When I use Visual Studio I really need [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/), in Eclipse I use [viPlugin](http://www.satokar.com/viplugin/), and so on.

Some time ago I was an Emacs user, now I can't use it without [Viper](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/emacs-20.7/html_chapter/viper_2.html).

However the productivity with Vi really comes when you are able to use commands without even thinking about them.

So, whatever editor you use, to get a real productivity gain the editor has to become an *extension of your hands*.

Comment: Yeah, luckily IDE's do provide accommodations for us Vim addicts.

Answer (score 1):

To do it *objectively*, you'd need something measurable.

If you've got enough free time on your hands to experiment, I suppose you could video record yourself using each editor for a few hours then add up the length of time you spent fighting each one...

Comment: But the result will still be awfully biased to the editor that you've got most experience with.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try out several different editors and see if you can *notice* any productivity gains from them.  If you don't then pick the one that appeals to you the most, if you do you will need to decide if the productivity gain outweighs the happiness you feel when using vim.

You might also want to consider different editors for different frameworks/languages.  I use vim for most of my C and Perl programming, a different editor for non-trivial Java applications, and another editor for developing in Rails, I haven't found a one-editor-fits-all yet.

Answer (score 0):

**I'd suggest simply measuring your actual output:**

- Use vim for one week and measure the actual output. Save the result as `V`.
- Use another editor for one week and measure the actual output. Save the result as `E`.

If `V` < `E`, then another editor has better productivity, otherwise vim is better choice for you.

---

Note that the hard part is *measuring the actual output*. For example, total lines of code or the size of `diff` output for the week could be poor methods. In addition, it may turn out that during the first week you were writing some easy code and during the second week you were trying to fix a really hard bug. As a result, you might be really benchmarking one work week to another, instead of one editor to another.

I guess it comes down to figuring out **what you're trying to accomplish and then deciding as objective measuring method for that as possible**. Then measure which editor gets better result.

I wouldn't even try measure the actual editor usage. A really high perfomance editor could be implemented as `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=1 > code.cpp` but the changes are high that your resulting code quality sucks a lot. If the output is good, nobody should care how you emitted it.

The actual editor usage should count only if you cannot physically use the editor for long time; for example, if the editor constantly requires switching between keyboard and mouse, you might develop RSI issues despite the fact that in the short term that editor would provide the best productivity.